# unable to understand how the group name is defined based on the chat room name while making a chat application using channels

Tags: python, django, django-channels

self.room_group_name = "chat_%s" % self.room_name
This is the line of code that defines the room group name from the room_name in the official tutorial on the channels website.
(https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/part_2.html)

I am unable to understand what "chat_%s" % self.room_name" means.
Would appreciate any explanation of what this bit of code exactly does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"chat_%s" % self.room_name
```

is an expression for formatting strings.  The `%s` is a replaceable parameter which gets populated with the values passed after the %.

Python3 has other formatting methods available that are roughly equivalent:

```
f"chat_{self.room_name}"
```

`f"chat_{self.room_name}"` is an f-string.  f-string is a shortcut for the string format function:

```
"chat_{room_name}".format( room_name = self.room_name )
```

Essentially, the formatting syntax you are asking about is this:

```
"template" % (param1, param2...)
```

The parameters in the template get replaced in order.  This is essentially an older deprecated way of formatting strings with variable interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

This is [*string formatting* <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting). It will produce a string where it will replace the `%s` with the `str(…)` on `self.room_name`. If `self.room_name` is thus `'foo'`, then it will produce a string `'chat_foo'`.

Nowadays [*f-strings* <sup>[pep-498]</sup>](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/) are used more commonly, so then one works with;

```
self.room_group_name = f'chat_{self.room_name}'
```